pandas ffill specific column and inplace warning related question
While I tried to give the ffill command with inplace as true for a particular column, it gave me a warning. However the result was correct as expected as I worked with only 1 column at a time.
>>> df['name'].ffill(inplace=True)
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment using an inplace method.
The behavior will change in pandas 3.0. This inplace method will never work because the intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a copy.

For example, when doing 'df[col].method(value, inplace=True)', try using 'df.method({col: value}, inplace=True)' or df[col] = df[col].method(value) instead, to perform the operation inplace on the original object.


>>>

However to have a good code as recommended, I wanted to try the method with inplace option still instead of assignment option given. However I'm not successful yet, not sure what mistake I'm making. Please help
>>> df.ffill({col: "name"}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'col' is not defined. Did you mean: 'cols'?
>>> df.ffill({cols: "name"}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> df.ffill({cols: name}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
>>> df.ffill({cols: 'name'}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> df.ffill({col: name}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'col' is not defined. Did you mean: 'cols'?
>>> df.ffill({cols: name}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
>>> df.ffill({cols: [name]}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
>>> df.ffill({cols: ['name']}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> df.ffill({cols: 'name'}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> df.ffill({name: }, inplace=True)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    df.ffill({name: }, inplace=True)
                         ^
SyntaxError: expression expected after dictionary key and ':'
>>> df.ffill({'name' }, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: NDFrame.ffill() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
>>> df.ffill('name', inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: NDFrame.ffill() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
>>> df.ffill({'name'}, inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: NDFrame.ffill() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
>>>


df.ffill({cols: 'name'}, inplace=True) 

to be successful without warning and do the update of df frame.

Is this what you're looking for? forward fill specific columns in pandas dataframe

Why don't you just use df['name'] = df['name'].ffill()?

It seems like the mistake you're making is misunderstanding the advice in the error. Read that again: df[col].method(value, inplace=True). .ffill doesn't take a value and df.ffill doesn't let you specify a subset of columns; that's more applicable to methods like .fillna. So the only equivalent is df[col] = df[col].method(), where col is 'name' and method is ffill.

As opposed to a language like JavaScript, in python this code {col: "name"}  is interpreted as a variable called col and not a key literal. Python tried to be helpful by suggesting the most similar valid variable in scope which is in this case cols. cols must be a list of some elements and now when you try {cols: "name"} python is trying to use the list of elements as the key for your dictionary. This is what's giving you  the unhashable type: 'list' errors.
